# How to apply color scale by field range?

Tags: altair

In vega-lite I'm able to apply color scale by field range, I'm able to use the field values of `color` field to color my chart ([this is the sample code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYcAvpO50AhoTl4QUOQFtMKEPMUBaABwwAbACYArHMwB2K9bYsTAFgCMRtgE4Wcx1f0AjOj8bMBg6EBkQNTkAJwBrLWjMMHFuTChIOhIkVBAAD2V4TAAbMOQ8kG5CAE8AB00yiGjM1SLw7iqCrBKtDsra+pBG5rlWiMgixuVquq0oCDUSEYqQQu6york-YuXKMBH60Gi5KAQDla7Sngno8IjiQiKB2+4AEl3GTCitMUIaymQAPQAtCYBByAB0CDgTFIfnBcAgAPenzkwNBcl0RWhmGBZnBJnBbHBACtKNBljo5JRMIRKMpKQZjOZLDY7A4XG5PN5fAEglYQqUANqgfLIZztFDiq6TMoAYlCfmMMGWIxqjCUyHMZm4Gy2rTKADloLoAGKNTCUFIgNAjUj1NgyEWSiWa7jjGUgWUsLxsExgFVFNUarU6zbbMpmxKW5Y2op2yWO8pil0sN0Qa5aeUwbPZgNBlBcEC68MgcyOGO2+plyQAXWkQA)).

I'm not able to rewrite in Python/altair, the same of this JSON.

```json
"color": {
  "type": "nominal",
  "field": "label",
  "scale": {"range": {"field": "color"}},
  "title": ""
}
```

It's not this

```py
chart=alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color=alt.Color('label:N',scale=range('color:N'))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `color=alt.Color('label:N').scale(range={"field": "color"})`

I have had the [reply](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/2916#discussioncomment-5077109) in altair discussions (thank you Christopher Davis)